# Why does scanf ask twice for input when there's a newline at the end of the format string?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *method1(void)
{
    static char a[4];
    scanf("%s\n", a);
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *h = method1();
    printf("%s\n", h);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code above, the prompt is asking me *twice* for input (I only use `scanf` once in the code). Why is that?

(I entered 'jo'; it asked for more input, so I entered 'jo' again.  Then it only printed out 'jo' once.)

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: That's a very short array.  Did you enter too much data?

Comment: I enter jo.
it ask for another input.
then I enter jo again.
then only it print out jo one time.

Comment: I know it is just a snippet, but you should **always** check the result of conversion functions like scanf and friends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-the-effect-of-trailing-white-space-in-a-scanf-format-string)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From my scanf manual page

> White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.  Everything else matches only itself.

Thus with `scanf ("%s\n", a)` it will scan for a string followed by optional white space. Since after the first newline more whitespace may follow, scanf is not done after the first newline and looks what's next. You will notice that you can enter any number of newlines (or tabs or spaces) and scanf will still wait for more.

However, when you enter the second string, the sequence of whitespace is delimited and scanning stops.

Use `scanf ("%s", a)` to not scan trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 13):

you have to remove the `\n` from the string format of the `scanf`. It should be

```
scanf("%s",a);
```

**EDIT: Explanation**

the `%s` means that the scanf reads the input character till it gets a delimiter which should be a white space like space or tab or new line(`\n`) so the first enter is get as a delimiter for the `"%s"` and adding the `"\n"` to the string format `"%s\n"` means that the scanf will wait 2 newlines the first newline is related to the delimiter of the `"%s"` and the second newline is related to the`\n` of the string format.

Comment: You're on the right track, but you've not said that `scanf` will keep reading white space until it comes across a non-space character.  You could enter many new lines (and blank or tabs) before a non-space is entered and stops `scanf`.  One more reason to prefer `fgets()` and `sscanf()` over the file I/O variants of `scanf()`.

Comment: Your reasoning about scanf waiting for two newlines is wrong. All newlines entered (even more than two) are scanned by the **single** `\n` in the format, as are any intermingled spaces and tabs. Please read the scanf specification in the C standard or the manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `\n` from the scanf format and give an input and it displays the output based on the given output once.

Comment: Wrong slash. Also, this answer adds nothing to previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either of these to avoid the mentioned problem :
`scanf("%s",a);`
or 
`scanf("\n%s",a);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Don't use \n on scanf, it won't ask you twice and sometimes it might show an error

**Your code**: `scanf("%s\n", a);`

**Try this on scanf**: `scanf("%s", a);`

Comment: The other answers stated this 8 years ago. This adds nothing new.

Answer (score -1):

use gets() or fgets() instead...alternatively use scanf("%[^\n]s",a);

Comment: scanf inputs into the array till you it receives a space..so use %[^\n]s...or dont use scanf, instead go for fgets() or gets()

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` is composed of two directives: `%[^\n]`, which either matches (and stores) one or more non-'\n' characters, or fails because it encountered a '\n' immediately, and `s` which matches a literal 's' and discards it, or fails and pushes the non-'s' character back onto stdin. The first directive will fail for consecutive attempts, because '\n' is not 's', so '\n' will be pushed straight back onto stdin and that is the first character encountered. See for yourself: `char a[64]; int n = scanf("%[^\n]s", a); assert(n == 1); n = scanf("%[^\n]s", a); assert(n == 1);`

Comment: My suggestion is to read the [fscanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/fscanf.html) manual so that you can clear up the confusion you have in regards to the `%[` directive and the `%s` directive.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the escape sequence in scanf stdio function

```
     scanf ("%s", a);
```

Comment: There's no explanation of why — and what happens when you do.  This adds nothing to the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15740060/) by [MOHAMED](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1003575/mohamed), or the accepted answer.