# Why scanf after the if block do not work it just displays "press 1 to enter again:" and do not take input again

Tags: c

`scanf` statement after if block is not working can somebody help me please

```
#include<stdio.h>
    main()
    {

        int input,itemno,input2;
        int name1,price1,name2,price2,name3,price3;
        printf("enter input:\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        if(input==1)
        {
            printf("enter number of items:\n");
            scanf("%d",&itemno);
            if(itemno<=3)
            {
                printf("enter name and age:\n");
                scanf("%d %d\n %d %d\n %d %d\n",&name1,&price1,&name2,&price2,&name3,&price3);
            }
         else
            printf("you can only enter 3 students");
     }
        printf("press 1 to enter again: \n");
        scanf("%d",&input2);
        if(input2==1)
        {
            printf("hey");
        }
    }
```

Comment: unchecked scanf return value... I smell danger....

Comment: Please don;t break the formatting. Read the posting guides.

Comment: Are you supposed to enter *numbers* for the "name"? Why do you need to enter name and prices three times? Why aren't you telling the user that he or she needs to enter three names and prices?

Comment: Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Just saying "is not working" is not enough. ***How*** is it "not working"? Have you checked what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns? Have you used a debugger to step through the code? That information should be in the question body.

Comment: I don't understand what this code is trying to do. Please clarify what you want to achieve with a sample output.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d %d\n %d %d\n %d %d\n",&name1,&price1,&name2,&price2,&name3,&price3);
```

Don't use escape characters in scanf function call.

Comment: Why not? Can you elaborate this?

Comment: just ignore what input is being provided. I wanted to ask that if first if statement gets true then why it dont go to scanf after if block

Comment: There are two if blocks. which one you are saying?

Comment: @Keine [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/scanf-asking-twice-for-input-while-i-expect-it-to-ask-only-one)

Answer (score 0):

just delete the last \n in your scanf 
the result is :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a40lR.png)

Comment: as for why?<\p>

Comment: this is because in scanf function ,the \n and space and the tabs ARE seen as blank symbols.

Comment: so if you have a \n in scanf , when you have entered 6 int, it wait for one another symbol to match the space blank causded by the \n.

Comment: and in the input buffer  when the scanf function finish ,there are also a extra symbol, when it runs to another scanf ,the scanf first scan the input buffer ,so cause the error!