# Program skips the last element of the array while reversing the order

Tags: c

The following program gets the input and reverses it but it seems to skip the last element of the array while doing so

```
/*C program that declares an array A and inputs n integer values in A.
Then the contents of array A is copied to another array B in reversed order. 
Finally print the elements of array B*/

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n, reverse, i ;
  int A[100], B[100] ;
  printf("Input the size of array A: ") ;
  scanf("%d", &n ) ;
  printf("Input the values of  A: ") ;
  for( i = 0 ; i<n ; i++ )
      scanf("%d ", &A[i] ) ;
  for(i = n-1 , reverse = 0 ; i>= 0 ; i--, reverse++)
      B[reverse] = A[i] ;
  for(i = 0 ; i<n ; i++ )
      A[i] = B[i];
  printf("Array B: ") ;
  for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++ )
      printf("%d ", A[i] ) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

Here is an online [repel](https://repl.it/JJd8/0) of the code demonstrating the problem

Comment: What is your input? Have you considered using a debugger to trace through the code and find the issue? 3, 1, 2, 3 seems to work fine other than saying you're going to print B when you print A.

Comment: "If i run this code then it takes all the input but it prints out one less data" --> rather than only _describe_ input and output, post the true input, output seen and expected output.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use the debugger**. BTW, read documentaton of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) and every function you are using

Comment: See [Trailing blank in `scanf()` format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19499060/what-is-difference-between-scanfd-and-scanfd) and don't use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is how you are formatting the scanf here

```
  for( i = 0 ; i<n ; i++ )
     scanf("%d ", &A[i] ) ;
```

The extra space after %d is messing up the input.  Input data has to match the formatting of scanf string exactly.  To fix this change to

```
  for( i = 0 ; i<n ; i++ )
     scanf("%d", &A[i] ) ;
```

this is because

> White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string
>   match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.
>   Everything else matches only itself.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15740124/2445295) explains it in detail

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine and printing all the data in reversed order provided you input the values of array by giving a space inbetween each, and all values at once.