# scanf with array index in C

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I wonder why scanf wants to get one more than the number of 'num' when I use this function for array index with infinite loop.

> 5       // The number of the index of an array.
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 // I put 5 numbers because I set the number of the index as 5. but..
>
> 6        // I had to put another number to finish the work of scanf.
>
> 1 2 3 4 5   // The numbers in the array. 6 has disappeared.

Here is a code that I made to test.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int n[100000] = { 0 };

    while (1) {
        scanf("%d ", &num);     

        if (num > 100000 || num <= 0) {
            printf("Input a number again. \n");
        }

        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                scanf("%d ", &n[i]);
            }

            // Test
            for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
                printf("%d ", n[k]);
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d "` --> `scanf("%d"`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It was simple!! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `scanf`, remove the additional whitespace after %d and it will run fine. Go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/scanf-asking-twice-for-input-while-i-expect-it-to-ask-only-one)  for further details.

Comment: Thank you. I could understand why the problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that  the problem is resulted from the additional space character you added it after the %d in scanf function. Try to remove that space character and see the output.