# Comparing string from FILE with other string

Tags: c, string, file, struct

Im trying to compare 2 strings with strcmp(). One of them is implemented by keyboard, but the other is scanned from a file, so i use `fgets(vec[i].nombre,80,fentrada);` where "vec" is a vector from a typedef struct, with a char variable named "nombre".
The thing is although I enter the exact same string which is taken from the file, it doesnt return a 0. I limited the maximum characters to the length of the string which is in the file, and it makes it work, so must have something to do with the blank spaces. But the point is making it work for whatever the length of the string is.

This is the structure:

```
typedef struct f{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int anno;
    };
typedef struct pelicula{
    char nombre[80];
    float nota;
    f fecha;
}peliculas;
peliculas vec[dim];
```

Here's the sentence to scan what is in the file.

```
FILE *fentrada=fopen("peliculas.dat","rt");
while(!feof(fentrada)){
    fgets(vec[i].nombre,80,fentrada);
    fscanf(fentrada,"%i",&vec[i].fecha.dia);
    fscanf(fentrada,"%i",&vec[i].fecha.mes);
    fscanf(fentrada,"%i",&vec[i].fecha.anno);
    fscanf(fentrada,"%f\n",&vec[i].nota);
    i++;
    printf("\n");
}
```

And this is where i compare the strings:

```
int i=0,j=0;
char *nombre,cos[46],c[66];
strcpy(c,vec[i].nombre);
gets(cos);
printf("%s\n",c);
printf("%i",strcmp(cos,c));
```

And this is what the file looks like:

```
Casa Blanca
4 11 2013
6
Mi villano favorito
5 11 2013
7
Crepusculo
6 11 2013
8
```

P.D, ive tried using scanf(%s) instead of fgets but it scans just "Casa", then "Blanca", so i get 6 elements instead of 3...

Comment: Grab your debugger and see what the strings are. Do note that `fgets()` stores the newline also in the result.

Comment: Lines read with `fgets` contain a `'\n'` at the end of the line, whereas lines read with `gets` don't. BTW `gets` has been deprecated long time ago, don't use it for real world programs; or better don't use it at all.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/), and [`gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: Also, it is odd (in the extreme) to read a line with `fgets()` and then read 3 integers and a `float` using `fscanf()`.  Remember, [`scanf()` leaves the newline in the input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer), and [Trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string is a UI disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/), though as long as the data really is coming from a file, it is OK.

Comment: Did my answer help you.? @Jose

Comment: @JayJoshi Sorry man i forgot to close the thread, minutes after posting i found the fix by myself! THX anyway!

Comment: @Jose, oh its ok. You can still select the answer if you feel it is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Possible Problems:

lines you read from file using `fgets` contains a new line character but `gets` doesn't. also using `feof(file)` is not advisable

#### Solution:

use `fscanf` instead of `fgets`. It returns a integer value which represents how many values are matched with the file input.

> fscanf returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

#### Code:

just change in the code for scanning the file lines

```
int ret;
while(ret = fscanf(fentrada,"%[0-9a-zA-Z ] %d %d %d %d ", vec[i].nombre, &vec[i].fecha.dia, &vec[i].fecha.mes, &vec[i].fecha.anno, &vec[i].nota))
{
    if(ret == EOF)
    {
        break;
    }else
    {
        // printf("\n %d",ret);
        // ^ prints how many values are successfully matched
    }
}
```

note: I have checked this code for your input. It works fine and returns 0 as the output of `strcmp`

reference: [fscanf - TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm)