# How to exit a scanf loop with newline character. Currently loops indefinitely

Tags: c

I am trying to get: `while(scanf("%c %c %d\n", &a, &b, &c) && (a!='\n'))` to exit once a line is blank, eg the following:

```
a b 12
q w 4
g u 80

(exit)
```

Code:

```
while(scanf("%c %c %d\n", &a, &b, &c) && (a != '\n'))
```

Comment: Note that [trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/) is almost invariably a very bad idea.

Comment: The `scanf()` family of file I/O functions does not respect newlines.  If you need to detect newlines, do not use `scanf()` et al.  (Using `sscanf()` is different — especially in combination with `fgets()`.)  Note that `scanf()` would be happy if the `a`, `b` and `12` are on separate lines, with an arbitrary number of newlines between each; it would also be happy if all 9 fields were on a single line.  It doesn't care — and the `\n` in the format doesn't mean "match a newline"; it means "match zero or more white space characters".

Answer (score 3):

To read a *line*, use `fgets()`.  Then, if successful,  parse the input string for `'\n'`, expected a,b,c, or anything else.

```
//                          c  ' '  c  ' '  d   \n  \0
#define LINE_EXPECTED_SIZE (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 11 + 1 + 1)

char buf[LINE_EXPECTED_SIZE * 2]; // let us be generous with size.
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) && buf[0] != '\n') {
  char a,b;
  int c;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%c %c %d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
    // Note unexpected input
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected bad input '%s'\n", buf);
    break;
  }
  printf("a:'%c', b:'%c', c%d\n", a,b,c);
}
```

---

`"\n"` is rarely correct at the end of a `scan()` format. [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799602/how-to-exit-a-scanf-loop-with-newline-character-currently-loops-indefinitely/52799718#comment92518878_52799602).

---

The above uses `sscanf(...) != 3` to detect if 3 specifiers were matched.  This will not detect if *extra* text was on the line.  An advanced approach uses `" %n"` to scan optional following white-space and then note the scan offset at that point.

```
  // if (sscanf(buf, "%c %c %d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%c %c %d %n", &a, &b, &c, &n);
  if (n == 0 || buf[n] != '\0') {
    // if scanning did not reach %n or extra text followed ...
```