# Why does this code give warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *' but argument 2 has type 'char(*)[11]'?

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define RIG 5
#define COL 11

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("swamp.txt","r");
    if((fp=fopen("swamp.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        puts("ERROR!");
        return -1;
    }
    char *swamp[RIG][COL];
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s",swamp)!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%s\n",swamp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm working with files and I'm getting 2 warnings for the `fscanf` inside the `while`.  Can somebody explain to me why?

Comment: change `char *swamp[RIG][COL];` to `char swamp[RIG * COL];`. Then `swamp` will have the correct type for `%s`.

Comment: It works but why?

Comment: Your `swamp` is a 2D array of pointers to `char`, but `%s` expects a pointer to `char` (or an array decaying to one).

Comment: So basically what you've done is adapting it from a 1D to a 2D array.Can you explain me why, after closing the file and printing swamp again only 1 row appears?

Comment: Because `swamp` variable stores only one (last) read value. Do you want to store all data from `swamp.txt` in `swamp` variable?

Comment: Yes because I need to work on it, how can i do that? I was thinking about using strcpy inside the while but it doesn't work

Comment: Note that [trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/) in general, doubly so if the input may be coming from a terminal.

Comment: There is no way to answer this without knowing what you are trying to do and what the expected file format is.

Answer (score 0):

For `test.txt` as below:

```
aaaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc
ddddddd eeeeeee fffffff
ggggggg hhhhhhh iiiiiii
jjjjjjj kkkkkkk lllllll
```

you can obtain data with this code (it can process words up to 8 characters in 4 rows and 3 columns):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum {
        ROWS = 4,
        COLS = 3
    };

    FILE *fp;
    char test[ROWS][COLS][9];
    int counter = ROWS * COLS;

    if ((fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS * COLS; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%8s", test[i / COLS][i % COLS]) == EOF) {
            counter = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        printf("%s ", test[i / COLS][i % COLS]);
        if ((i + 1) % COLS == 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do so only with for cicles?

Comment: What do you mean? What would you like to get rid of?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `swamp.txt` contains:

```
marsh
bog
quagmire
morass
fen
```

and that you want to read these lines into the array `swamp` in your program.  Then you might revise your code along these lines.  Notice that this avoids opening the file twice, amongst other cleanup operations.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RIG 5
#define COL 11

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "swamp.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }
    char swamp[RIG][COL];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < RIG && fscanf(fp, "%10s", swamp[i]) == 1)
        i++;

    fclose(fp);

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", j, swamp[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0: marsh
1: bog
2: quagmire
3: morass
4: fen
```

Note that the code protects against overflow from a long file by counting words as they're read.  You already checked `fopen()` — that was good.  I improved the error message, though.  In my opinion, you should never call `fopen()` with a literal string for the file name because when you report an error on opening the file, you need the file name in the error message, so you'd have to repeat yourself.  I fixed the type of the array so it is a 2D array of `char` and not a 2D array of (uninitialized) `char` pointers.  I arranged to pass each row of the array to `fscanf()` in turn.  I limited the length of the input for each word to prevent overflows there, too.