# Reading different datatype from .txt file

Tags: c

I want to read data from a text file and store the data.

I can not all the data using `getc()` as it will take all the data at once, and I do not know how to distribute that for my use.

Data is in form of:
John
Sebastian
1
2 //Number of notes(So, when I read this value and run a loop to collect all 
    notes)
12 //note 1
21 //note 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct StudentDetails
{
    char firstName[100], secondName[100];
    int notes[100][30], id;
    struct StudentDetails *next;
};

int main()
{
    FILE *input;
    input = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (!input)
    {

        while (input != EOF)
        {
             //what to do to store in different variable rather in one.
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: `getc()` returns **one** character (cast to an int) or EOF. If that is too much for you, you should not call it.

Comment: You can use `fread` to read blocks from the file.

Comment: I've written something like this in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648517/why-does-this-code-give-warning-format-s-expects-type-char-but-argument/54650085#54650085). Maybe `fscanf()` in loop will be suitable for you?

Comment: while() {        fread("%c", &firstName);             fread("%c", &SecondName);               
     fread("%c", &id); } Will this work? @WernerHenze

Comment: You did not read the man page for `fread`, but you should do so.

Comment: This can be done with the fscanf() function. we can give the format specifier in such a manner that it can read multiple format at once, it works similar to scanf(). But the problem with fscanf() is that it will be dependent on the content in the file. we should know the way in which the file content are stored. also we have to give proper width and precision specifier with format specifier  to make sure that content read from the file will not over flow the assigned variable.

Comment: Following show a simple example but for loop it will become complicated: if the file have number first and then name with a space in each line then you can do: fscanf (fd, "%d %[^\n]", &id, &name); this will fetch the first integer in id and next string in name. but this have draw back, you have to make sure of reading the next line properly as it will consider new line character again. so you have to write some more logic to fetch next line properly.

Answer (score -3):

Please try fread() function for reading a record from a file and fwrite(), it's used to write a record to the file.
eg: fwrite(&sd,sizeof(sd),1,input);
for student record no need of struct StudentDetails *next; (we are not doing anything like linked list, we just write different student record in a file. So you just define structure variable as StudentDetails SD in main that is more than enough each iteration of loop you can write one student record to file.)
for reading you can use

```
while(fread(&sd,sizeof(sd),1,input) > 0 )
{
   printf("Name:%s",sd.name);//this you can do ...      
}
```

I hope it will help you :)