# Why does scanf ask twice for input

Tags: c++, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char karakter1, karakter2, karakter3;

  printf("Input 3 karakter terserah\n");

  printf("Input karakter :\n");
  scanf("%c ", &karakter1);

  printf("Input karakter :\n");
  scanf("%c ", &karakter2);

  printf("input Karakter :\n");
  scanf("%c ", &karakter3);

  printf("\n");
  printf("Karakter yang diinputkan adalah %c \n", karakter3);
  printf("Karakter yang diinputkan adalah %c \n", karakter2);
  printf("Karakter yang diinputkan adalah %c \n", karakter1);

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the code above, the terminal ask *twice* input (
in ubuntu, windows is running normally). i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/why-does-scanf-ask-twice-for-input-when-theres-a-newline-at-the-end-of-the-form)
answer, and still no changes although there isn't white space

[this my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3ilM.png)

Comment: your code is asking 3 times for input. Please be more clear about what is expected and what the code does. You can include input, expected and actual output in the question directly

Comment: and please only tag the language you are actually using. Even if your code can compile as C or as C++, I doubt that you do compile it as both

Comment: Because `scanf` must know when the white-space ends, you must give some non-space extra input. Always use *leading* space instead.

Comment: And **always** check the return value from `scanf()` so you know if it worked or not.  `scanf()` is not a good way to get input - it's too easy for input to cause it to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine for you now.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(){
  char karakter1, karakter2, karakter3;

  printf("Input 3 karakter terserah\n");

  printf("Input karakter :\n");
  scanf(" %c", &karakter1);

  printf("Input karakter :\n");
  scanf(" %c", &karakter2);

  printf("input Karakter :\n");
  scanf(" %c", &karakter3);

  printf("\n");
  printf("Karakter yang diinputkan adalah %c \n", karakter3);
  printf("Karakter yang diinputkan adalah %c \n", karakter2);
  printf("Karakter yang diinputkan adalah %c \n", karakter1);

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```